# Authentication with Spring-Security via Active Directory LDAP

Tags: spring, spring-security, active-directory, ldap, spring-ldap

I can't authenticate using a real active directory, let me explain better I tried to authenticate using the example proposed by spring.io without problem where a internal service is started without any problem.
reference https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/

I tried to modify the code below by inserting the configuration of my active directory without success. Can you kindly guide me or show me a real case where a true connection is made without using internal services like those in the examples? I looked on the net but found everything similar to the official example without any real case

```
@Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
                .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
                .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
                .contextSource()
                    .url("ldap://localhost:8389/dc=springframework,dc=org")
                    .and()
                .passwordCompare()
                    .passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder())
                    .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
    }
```

Error show:
Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0907C2, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v2580

Comment: LDAP based practices is to search for the EntryDN and then perform authentication using the found DN and the provided password. It's quite strange that the guide shows the usage of a DN partner as first choice. Only in very rare cases the Directory Information Tree would be a 'flat' one.

Password comparison is also bad practise.

Comment: Also typically anonymous access to productive Directory Servers is not allowed, so you need a 'service Account' (special Bind-DN), which can be used to perform LDAP operations against the Directory Server.

Answer (score 9):

Yeah, authentication via LDAP that's too painful. In order to be able to perform authentication to AD you need to use the **ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider**.
Here is the working sample:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adProvider =
            new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("domain.com", "ldap://localhost:8389");
    adProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
    adProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
    auth.authenticationProvider(adProvider);
}
```

And to save your time just read the following, that's really important:
[AD authentication doc](https://www.docs4dev.com/docs/en/spring-security/5.1.2.RELEASE/reference/advanced-topics.html#ldap-active-directory)

Answer (score 1):

I found a sample over here, which was useful:

https://github.com/sachin-awati/Mojito/tree/master/webapp/src/main/java/com/box/l10n/mojito/security

You **can optionally implement** `UserDetailsContextMapperImpl` which overrides `mapUserFromContext` to create the `UserDetails` object if the user is not found during the Active Directory lookup - `loadUserByUsername`.

```java
@Component
public class UserDetailsContextMapperImpl implements UserDetailsContextMapper {

    @Override
    public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations dirContextOperations, String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {

        UserDetails userDetails = null;

        try {
            userDetails = userDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(username);

        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException e) {
            String givenName = dirContextOperations.getStringAttribute("givenname");
            String surname = dirContextOperations.getStringAttribute("sn");
            String commonName = dirContextOperations.getStringAttribute("cn");

            userDetails = userDetailsServiceImpl.createBasicUser(username, givenName, surname, commonName);
        }

        return userDetails;
    }
```

Ensure you are using the `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` spring security class as Active Directory has its own nuances compared to other LDAP servers. You'll probably need to be using the `@EnableGlobalAuthentication` annotation in your security configuration class as you can have multiple `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`s which confuses things a lot.

```
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adProvider =
                new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("domain.com", "ldap://primarydc.domain.com:389");
        adProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        adProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        auth.authenticationProvider(adProvider);
}
```

More details here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4324
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4571